# Linq method to select only one condition from a datatable?

Tags: c#, linq

Having `DataTable` with bulk of data. and i need to select only one type of `AccType` from the `DataTable` ,

Right now, if there is Accounts with **A,E,I,O,U** and if, i need to select an account type with `'I'` I will remove all other Accounts from the table via `linq` method. find the following code.

```
 DataTable dt = (DataTable)this.ViewState["Account"];
 CopyTAble = dt.Copy();
 SeledAcc = CopyTAble;
 DataRow[] rows;
 string AccType = "";
 if (dt != null)
 {
     string AType = "E";
     string BType = "A";
     string CType = "U";
     string DType = "O";
     string EType = "I";
     
     if (AccType == "I")
     {
         rows = SeledAcc.Select("AccType = '" + AType + "'");  
         foreach (DataRow row in rows)
             SeledAcc.Rows.Remove(row);
         rows = SeledAcc.Select("AccType = '" + BType + "'");  
         foreach (DataRow row in rows)
             SeledAcc.Rows.Remove(row);
         rows = SeledAcc.Select("AccType = '" + CType + "'"); 
         foreach (DataRow row in rows)
             SeledAcc.Rows.Remove(row);
         rows = SeledAcc.Select("AccType = '" + DType + "'");  
         foreach (DataRow row in rows)
             SeledAcc.Rows.Remove(row);
     }
    }
```

My question as per the optimization process, there is any simple way to select the desired account type in a single line?

Comment: Also, the `DataTable` / `DataRow` types are not strongly-typed and don't implement `IEnumerable<T>` (where `T` is some class that you defined) - so there's no point using Linq with them _unless_ you're okay with using `IEnumerable<DataRow>` - or manually projecting a `DataRow` into a custom (zero-cost) `struct` wrapper for strongly-typed column accesses.

Comment: My question as per the optimization process, there is any simple way to select the desired account type in a single line?

Comment: Do you mean like `SeledAcc.Rows.AsEnumerable().Where( r => r["AccType"] == "I" )`?  I'm not sure what you mean by "optimization" though...

Comment: Your code is **not** actually using Linq at all - the `.Select(String)` method you're calling is a member of `DataTable` and predates Linq by about 4 years.

Comment: Use `OR` in one statement.

Comment: What means "select the desired account type" at all? Do you want all DataRows with a matching AccType?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes,

Comment: @Dai , showing the error with DataRow Collection does not a definition for AsEnumerable

Comment: @Dev i guess Dai wants to post something like `SeledAcc.AsEnumerable().Where( r => r["AccType"] == "I" )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Where` and `CopyToDataTable`:

```
DataTable matchingRowsTable;
try
{
    matchingRowsTable = SeledAcc.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(row => row.Field<string>("AccType") == AccType)
        .CopyToDataTable();
}
catch (InvalidOperationException) // thrown if there were no matching rows
{
    matchingRowsTable = SeledAcc.Clone(); // empty table with same columns
}
```

I have handled the `InvalidOperationException` because it's thrown in [`CopyToDataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable?view=net-8.0) if there are no matching rows. This is the most efficient way to handle this.

Comment: thanks, i got the solution by your answer. thanks for your support.